# Site requires base url to include index.php for it to work

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, virtualhost, scalr

We are testing our using scalr. We have a site set-up in the folder `/var/www/subdomain.example.com/public_html` with the following virtualhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAlias www.{$host} {$server_alias}
       ServerAdmin {$server_admin}
       DocumentRoot {$document_root}
       ServerName {$host}
       ErrorLog {$logs_dir}/http-{$host}-error.log
       CustomLog {$logs_dir}/http-{$host}-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When we goto `subdomain.example.com` it displays the hosts default message e.g. "Welcome to Scalr" - but if we go to `subdomain.example.com/index.php` the site is working. Is there a way to get the base url to direct to the index.php without showing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

More resources on that: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html

In your case:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # (other directives)
  DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

*Update*

As `jcjr` suggested, this directive can be also put inside `.htaccess` file, but ensure, that you've enabled such method by proper `AllowOverride` directive value:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html

Comment: Probably the best way to do it. Using .htaccess file might be another option.